# How to open webpages/read input via programming language

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that starting with a particular URL will open all the links in that URL only and totals the number of times a specific string of characters (regardless of case) occurs on all the links combined. I want it to be automated, but I have no idea how to make the webtext an input into the language. Can you guys help?

So for example, for this page it would be continuous program that when this URL is entered, it would go sequentially down the page, with each iteration being: (it goes to the link, counts the # of occurrences on that link's URL page, then goes back to the original URL, goes one link down) and continues until there are no more clickable links left.

I am not asking you to write it for me, but I don't even know how to approach this problem. So if you could offer me any guides that would be helpful it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the java.net package. Basically read the html into a string or something and search it for <a href../> tags while keeping a running total?

Comment: Look into using `HttpUrlConnection`.